# How can I strip out logic from a UserControl (View) to the Presenter

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

This is my very first attempt to make MVP work with WinForms. I do have a much larger project in mind. However, here I have a very simple attempt at a WinForms MVP example. I have only one model, one Form, and two Views. The Presenter is wired up in Program.cs. Everything does work. However, with one particular User Control I can’t seem to refactor the rest of the business logic out into the Presenter. I am trying to make an example that is easily modified as a demo project. I am really not looking for simply getting it to work but rather I am looking for the “canon” answer, if there is such a thing. Any help or advice you could offer world be appreciated. Even a push in the right direction would be a great help.

My MainFormPresenter:

```
internal class MainFormPresenter
{
    private readonly SimpleContext _context = new SimpleContext();
    private readonly IMainFormView _mainFormView;
    private readonly IPeopleListView _peopleListView;
    private readonly IPersonInfoView _personInfoView;

    public MainFormPresenter(IMainFormView mainFormView)
    {
        _peopleListView = mainFormView.PeopleListView;
        _personInfoView = mainFormView.PersonInfoView;

        _mainFormView = mainFormView;
        mainFormView.Load += MainFormViewOnLoad;
        mainFormView.FormClosed += MainFormViewOnFormClosed;

        _peopleListView.SelectionChanged += OnSelectedNameChanged;
    }

    private void OnSelectedNameChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = _peopleListView.GetSelectedId();
        Person person = _context.People.Find(id);

        _personInfoView.SetFirstName(person.FirstName);
        _personInfoView.SetLastName(person.LastName);
        _personInfoView.SetBirthDate(person.BirthDate);
    }

    private void MainFormViewOnFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    private void MainFormViewOnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _context.People.Load();

        BindingList<Person> people = _context.People.Local.ToBindingList();

        _peopleListView.SetDataSource(people);
    }
}
```

My Code-Behind for my PeopleListView:

```
public partial class PeopleListView : UserControl, IPeopleListView
{
    private readonly BindingSource _bSource;

    public PeopleListView()
    {
        _bSource = new BindingSource();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int GetSelectedId()
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = PeopleGridView.CurrentRow;

        if (row != null)
        {
            Person person = (Person)row.DataBoundItem;
            return person.PersonId;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public void SetDataSource(BindingList<Person> people)
    {
        _bSource.DataSource = people;
        _bSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;

        PeopleGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        PeopleGridView.DataSource = _bSource;
    }

    private void PeopleGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectionChanged?.Invoke(new object(), new EventArgs());
    }

    public event EventHandler SelectionChanged;
}
```

Now how do I extract this logic back to the Presenter? The MVP Pattern (according to Pluralsight’s - Windows Forms Best Practices) states the Views shouldn’t care about the data it is displaying. e.g. Separation of Concerns. But I want my view to update when the model changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be canon but, here is how I handled it. Constructive criticism is still very much welcomed. Plain ol’ just calling me a thoughtless idiot or telling me what I did or did not do correctly is find as well.

My modified Presenter:

```
internal class MainFormPresenter
{
    private readonly SimpleContext _context = new SimpleContext();
    private readonly IMainFormView _mainFormView;
    private readonly IPeopleListView _peopleListView;
    private readonly IPersonInfoView _personInfoView;

    public MainFormPresenter(IMainFormView mainFormView)
    {
        _peopleListView = mainFormView.PeopleListView;
        _personInfoView = mainFormView.PersonInfoView;

        _mainFormView = mainFormView;
        _mainFormView.Load += MainFormViewOnLoad;
        _mainFormView.FormClosed += MainFormViewOnFormClosed;

        _peopleListView.SelectionChanged += OnSelectedNameChanged;
    }

    private void OnSelectedNameChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = _peopleListView.GetSelectedRow();
        Person person = (Person) row.DataBoundItem;

        _personInfoView.SetFirstName(person.FirstName);
        _personInfoView.SetLastName(person.LastName);
        _personInfoView.SetBirthDate(person.BirthDate);
    }

    private void MainFormViewOnFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    private void MainFormViewOnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _context.People.Load();

        BindingList<Person> people = _context.People.Local.ToBindingList();

        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource
        {
            DataSource = people,
            RaiseListChangedEvents = true
        };

        _peopleListView.SetDataSource(bSource);
    }
}
```

My Modified User Control (View):

```
public partial class PeopleListView : UserControl, IPeopleListView
{
    public PeopleListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DataGridViewRow GetSelectedRow()
    {
        return PeopleGridView.CurrentRow;
    }

    public void SetDataSource(BindingSource bSource)
    {
        PeopleGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        PeopleGridView.DataSource = bSource;
    }

    private void PeopleGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectionChanged?.Invoke(new object(), new EventArgs());
    }

    public event EventHandler SelectionChanged;
}
```